# Shelltile not getting updated properly in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am trying to get tweets from my twitter account and display the top most tweet on my shell tile. So i created a background agent(periodic task) to do it. Every 30 mins the background agent should access my twitter timeline and get my top most tweet and display it in the tile. The problem is my tile is getting updated only once i.e when i start the agent, afterwards its not getting updated.

Here is my background agent code:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    ShellToast popupMessage = new ShellToast()
    {
        Title = "My First Agent",
        Content = "Background Task Launched",
    };

    WebClient twitter = new WebClient();
    twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
    twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=dnivra26"));
    popupMessage.Show();
}

private void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        return;

    XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

    var message2 = (from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                    select tweet.Element("text").Value).FirstOrDefault();

    UpdateAppTile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + message2.ToString());
}

private void UpdateAppTile(string message)
{
    ShellTile appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
    if (appTile != null)
    {
        StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackContent = message
        };

        appTile.Update(tileData);
        //NotifyComplete();
    }
}
```

i am able to get the top tweet only once.

Answer (score 2):

You must call NotifyComplete() when you are done. If not the scheduling of the task will be aborted. Why have you commented it out?

Answer (score 2):

I never tried it before but this looks like a nice example to write a periodical background agent.

My guess is that you should call NotifyComplete() at the end, that tells the OS that your task is ready.

[Periodical Agent on Windows Phone 7](http://wildermuth.com/2011/09/06/Periodic_Agents_on_Windows_Phone_7_1)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to call `NotifyComplete()` upon the completion. However, since you use a asynchronous event, `WebClient.DownloadStringCompleted`, you need to lock the execution until the download string have completed.

For this, I recommend to use the [Task Parallel Library for Silverlight](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks).

What you would need to do, is something like this:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    ShellToast popupMessage = new ShellToast()
    {
        Title = "My First Agent",
        Content = "Background Task Launched",
    };
    popupMessage.Show();

    UpdateTile().ContinueWith(x => NotifyComplete());
}

private Task<bool> UpdateTile()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    WebClient twitter = new WebClient();

    twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
        else
        {
            XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

            var message2 = xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                                    .Select(x => x.Element("text").Value).FirstOrDefault();

            ShellTile appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

            if (appTile != null)
            {
                StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData
                {
                    BackContent = DateTime.Now.ToString() + message2.ToString()
                };

                appTile.Update(tileData);

                tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            }
        }
    };

    twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=dnivra26"));

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: how do i install the System.Threading.Tasks package in "visual studio 2010 express for windows phone". I am new to windows mobile development. Please help me through this.

Comment: I installed the package and did the changes as you said. But this line "var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);" is showing "UnauthorizedAccessException". What am i to do now??

Comment: @ClausJørgensen the link to your guide is broken